# have the url for an external link come from a variable angular

Tags: angular, external-links

I have a situation where I want to get some url's from a database via an api and then have those (external) links on my page.

So I want to do something like this:

component.ts

```
public url: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.url = getFromAPI()
}
```

component.html

```
<a href="{{url}}"> here's a link </a>
```

but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it.
I've tried to use the attribute directive approach here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-external-links?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexternal-url.directive.ts

But I must be doing it wrong because it's not working for me; my link still comes out as
https://localhost:4200/urlFromAPI

I've also tried the approach described here:
https://kevinphelps.me/blog/2017-06-30-handling-external-links-in-angular

but then my links don't work at all. Clicking on them does nothing.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing? Or is this actually difficult in Angular?

Comment: Not sure, what you want to achieve, Are you looking for `target="_blank"` or Are you getting `router-links` from API or you want to open link in next page?

Comment: I want to have a link to an external website from an Angular application, with the value for the href coming from a variable, and not have the Angular router assume that it's supposed to be an internal link.Look at the second link I posted in my question, that's the most recent thing I've tried to implement to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your stackblitz app, Your set default value as `false` in you `deactivateGuard`. So that, the navigation has blocked over there.

Here, I need a confirmation from user whether navigate or not using `window.confirm('Are you sure?')`.

In your routing.module.ts File:

```
{
   provide: deactivateGuard,
   useValue: () => {
     console.log('Guard function is called!')         
     return window.confirm("Are you sure?");
   }
}
```

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-external-links-aph8hk?file=src%2Fapp%2Frouting.module.ts

Let me know if it's worked.

Comment: that didn't work. When I click the link, it still tries to take me to "https://localhost:4200/www.google.com" for example

Comment: can you add you environment file here?

Answer (score 0):

OK. If the link starts with "http[s]://", angular won't assume it's an internal link. That's all.